# Configuring ADFS 2.0 as SAML identity provider for b2c

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, adfs

Can I add ADFS 2.0 as a SAML identity provider using custom policies in Azure Active Directory B2C.

Comment: Yeah it is possible: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-setup-adfs2016-idp and you can also refer to this link for settings details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/saml-technical-profile

Answer (score 1):

It supports, check the article at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-setup-adfs2016-idp

Comment: I can't find any place in the document that's say it's support ADFS 2.0. I think the doc is referring to ADFS 4.0. What I know Azure B2C only understand OpenID Connect protocol and ADFS 2.0 does not support this protocol. Only 4.0 does

Comment: From your question What I understand is, you want ADFS as a SAML provider and that article will work for that

Comment: I found here that only ADFS 4.0 supports this configuration 
 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuredev/2017/06/23/using-adfs-as-an-identity-provider-for-azure-ad-b2c/

Comment: Try in your version and check. if you stuck anywhere just drop a comment here